# Python method 'count leaves'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote this class:

```
class TNode(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self._children=[]
    def add(self, c):
        self._children.append(c)
    def name(self):
        return self.name
    def children(self):
        t=[]
        for f in self._children:
            t+=[f]
        return t
    def count(self, *ciao):
        cnt = 1
        for node in self._children:
            cnt += node.count()
        return cnt
    def count_by_name(self, name):
        cbn=1
        for node in self._children:
            if node.name == name:
                cbn += node.count()
        return cbn
```

Now I need a method to count the leaves of a tree. How can I write this method?

Comment: Have you tried using google ? There are plenty well known algorithms for this exact issue.

Comment: yes i try but there is nothing that can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
def leafcounter(node):
    if isinstance(node, dict):
        return sum([leafcounter(node[n]) for n in node])
    else:
        return 1
    leafcounter(tree)
```